# installation 5.0.1 keys.yaml and config.yaml missing

Tags: mitmproxy

After installating 5.0.1, I tried to configure mitmproxy.However, i could not find keys.yaml and config.yaml in the users directory (installer on Windows 10) or anywhere on the disk.

Also i was not able to enter any command in the mitmproxy cmd-window. entering ":" didnt do anything.

Is the installation in windows 10 broken?

regards,
   Arno

Answer (score 0):

1. "mitmproxy" is only available on Linux/OSX, you are probably just running the non-interactive mitmdump (see https://docs.mitmproxy.org/stable/overview-installation/#windows)
2. You have to manually create these files in /.mitmproxy/. They are just empty/nonexisting by default.

Comment: Actually, I am running mitmweb.exe. It has an intractive proxy, and I tried it, it did work for me. I just wanted to change the listening port. It seems that throught the web interface this is not possible, so I was trying configure.yaml. Do you have an emaple for configure.yaml? thanks.